# WebSphere DynaCache deserialization issue

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, websphere, websphere-portal, dynacache

I have two portal web project

project1

project2

I have a shared library(sharedLibrary.jar) set which is used in both the above project. My shared library is used to lookup dyna cache and set/get data from it.

I am setting a my own bean bean(say it is com.test.UserBean) to dyna cache from project 1.

Now from project 2 am trying to retrieve the bean(com.test.UserBean) from cache. When doing so i am getting classCastException.

but when I assign it like below it was showing me the that the object is com.test.UserBean

Object obj=distributedMap.get();
My bean implements Serializable interface and has a serialVersionUID field.

I am not sure what happening here. Is it a class loader issue/something else.

Can any one shed some more light on this ?

Comment: How have you deployed your shared library? Also, can you post the full stack trace?

Answer (score 1):

This is less likely a serialization issue and more likely a classloader issue.

If the class was truly loaded by both portlet web applications by a single, common class loader then instances can be shared via DynaCache.

If however two *different* classloaders are used to load the *same* .class from the same .jar (on disk) and the two applications share a single instance (e.g. via DynaCache distributed map) you will encounter a `ClassCastException` - even though, as you've seen, `myInstance.getClass().getName()` yields the same string.

To confirm this you can [enable a service](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/utrb_classload_viewer_service.html) and use the [WebSphere classloader viewer](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/utrb_classload_viewer.html). This will let you, per module, troubleshoot your "two classloaders, one class" issue.  There  is a companion doc on the InfoCenter doc which walks you through the [troubleshooting process](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/ttrb_classload_viewer.html).  The classloader viewer will show you which .jar and which classloader was used to load the `com.test.UserBean` in each module.  For example, you may have accidentally packaged the jar in WEB-INF/lib of one and not the other and have parent-last classloading enabled.